# Dekujs component cache and animation

Tags: javascript, performance, animation

How does the dekujs cache work? In the below case, which will benefit most of it?

E.G: **A component for FontAwesome icons**

```
import { h } from 'deku';

function IconFn(icon) {
  return h('span', {class: 'fa fa-' + icon})
}

const IconComp = 
  ({ props }) => h('span', {class: 'fa fa-' + props.icon})

// And then we use them
h('div', {class: 'icons'}, [
  IconFn('angle-left'),
  h(IconComp, {icon: 'angle-right'})
])
```

Also, is it legit to change the dom directly for, say, complex animation using some third party lib like `greensocks`? I suppose it's a little tricky to get it right in some cases, but levering the `onUpdate` and `onRemove` it should be possible, isn't it?

Comment: The two functions you make (`IconFn` and `IconComp`) are literally exactly the same thing. Neither will benefit more from any kind of caching.

Comment: Nope, their not. The first one will return a `native node`, while the latter will be a `thunk node`.
Thank you for the dekujs tag, I couldn't create it xD

Comment: I can't imagine that. They both return whatever `h()` returns, because all they do is call `h()`. The differences in notation are smoke and mirrors, deku.js won't even notice them.

Comment: There's nothing to imagine about, please, read the source code for `h` (it's internally called `create`), you can found it here: https://github.com/dekujs/deku/blob/master/src/element/index.js#L36

Comment: This checks if `type` is a function or not. In both cases in your code sample type is the string (`'span'`), so none of your calls above will return a thunk element.

Comment: Please, read more carefully the example. When I use the `IconComp` I don't call it but simply pass it as the first argument of `h`, therefore the second child will be a `thunk` and not `native`. `IconComp` will be called later and not immediately

Comment: Yes, then the result of calling `h()` it is different. I was *explicitly* talking about `IconFn` and `IconComp`, because that is what your question seems to be about. You can call `h(IconFn,  {icon: 'angle-right'})`, it would be 100% the same thing.